# Can't run on device after installing iOS 4.2 and the 4.2 SDK

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, ios-4.2

I installed iOS 4.2 on my 2nd-generation iPod Touch last week. I tried running my application on the device through Xcode, but it didn't work (because Xcode didn't yet support iOS 4). To solve that, I installed Xcode 3.2.5 and the iOS SDK 4.2. Now I can get the app to run in the iPhone/iPad Simulator just fine.

However, I can no longer select "Device" from the menu at the top of the screen. It's a choice, but when I try to click on it, it never actually gets a check mark.

[image: Can't select Device from the XCode menu]

Because of this, I can no longer run the app on my iPod. The other (related) problem is that I can't choose "Build and Archive" from the Build menu anymore because the target is not a device.

Why is this happening? Do I need to change some settings in my project, or something with my device itself?

**EDIT:** Upon closer investigation, it appears that I can't select anything but the iPhone Simulator 4.0. Maybe there's something wrong with the project file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that the base SDK is set to **Latest iOS (currently set to iOS 4.2)** for your Xcode project and your target's product, then perform a rebuild and see if your iPod is recognized.

Also try visiting the Xcode Organizer and see if it's asking for anything from your iPod. Typically Xcode will want to collect some data from devices whose OS receive updates, so it can update itself and install your apps on the updated OS properly.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had done both of those already, but checking them again didn't seem to solve the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try unplugging and reconnecting your iPod. Or perhaps a reboot.

Comment: I figured it out! The Release config still had the base SDK set to iphoneos4.0. I had been looking at the Debug config the whole time (which was correct, but not the config that was causing the problem). So your solution solved it. Thanks a bunch!